# asp.net mvc Jquery Delete empty row from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the code in my partial view i'm using BeginCollectionItem.

```
<tr>

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("QuoteLines"))
{
    <td>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuoteID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuoteLineID)
    </td>
    <td class="visible-lg  col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Group, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Group, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-5">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
    <td class="visible-md visible-lg col-md-2  col-lg-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="delete form-control btn-default" data-id="@model.QuoteLineID">Delete</button>
    </td>
}
```

The important part is the delete button, it has a class referenced by javascript to delete the row. But for some reason it does not execute the code if the row has no data.

```
<button type="button" class="delete form-control btn-default" data-id="@model.QuoteLineID">Delete</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteQuoteLine")'; // assumes its in the same controller
$('.delete').click(function () {


    if (confirm('verwijderen?')) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        if (id == 0) { // or if(id == 0) depending if your property is nullable
            row.remove(); // the item never existed so no need to call the server
            return;
        }
        $.post(url, { ID: id }, function (response) {
            if (response) {
                row.remove(); // OK, so remove the row
            } else {
                // Oops - display and error message?
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: So you don't even see the `confirm`?... my second question ... are you sure your `id == 0`... or is the attribute just `undefined`?... Final question... does you row with no data even renders if it has no data? is it part of your QuoteLines property?

Comment: I would throw a null coalescence on that id, `data-id="@(model.QhoteLineID ?? "0")"`  Or better yet, wrap it in an `if` that checks if the id is there.

Comment: Its capital M `data-id="@Model.QuoteLineID"` (not `@model`) but I assume that is just a typo. What do you mean _row has no data_? Are you referring to adding a new row using ajax? And what `type` is the `QuoteLineID` property?

Comment: If i use F12 to look at the result the lines i just added, where the input fields are empty all have `data-id=0`
One of my working buttons would be:
`<button type="button" class="delete form-control btn-default" id="Test" data-id="126">Delete</button>`
Not working look like:
`<button type="button" class="delete form-control btn-default" id="Test" data-id="0">Delete</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by row has no data?  If row has no data, thus there is no numerical ID value stored in `data-id`, then the reason could be is the post expects there to be an ID of a valid type, but it's null, thus the Action method is throwing an error (which would be caught using ASP.NET error handling... if you are logging those errors, check the log).  To verify that, use a networking tool to see if it is making the request to the server, and returning an error response.

Can you please post the action method signature?  That would help to see.

Comment: In the case of no data the `data-id` is 0.
And it does not reach the javascript code, i have a breakpoint at 
`if(confirm...` , it never hits it.

If i try to post the rows and they come back from the server with some 'is required' annotations. i can delete them. prior to that, the delete event is not launched. 
Even tho the `data-id` is till 0 they work

Comment: So to get the original set of data, you pull it in via AJAX?

Comment: The first set is 
`@foreach (var QuoteLine in Model)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_QuoteLineCollectionItem", QuoteLine);
                }`
The extra rows (who are not responding) are Ajax action
`Ajax.ActionLink("Create QuoteLine", "AddQuoteLine", "Quotes", new { QuoteID  = Model.FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0: Model.First().QuoteID }, new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "targetID"`

Comment: OK and the delete button is in AJAX response right?  Any AJAX content does not automatically get attached to the `$('.delete').click(function () {})` handler; you have to manually attach again to those objects.  The `$("#").on("click", function() { })` is supposed to; it never worked for me, but I was probably doing it wrong :-)

Comment: It worked perfectly. I am now left wondering why i use a 'template' ( partial class) to create new items. It seems like it is not taking the implemented logic with it.